# Email Style Rendering Issue in Gmail for Laravel Application

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I have an email delivery system developed in Laravel. It works well, but the issue I'm facing is that the styles are not displaying correctly in Gmail's email boxes, whereas they appear correctly in other messaging providers such as Outlook.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or something I'm missing?

in resources/views, I have the following template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Digital Citizen</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Our first page">
        <meta name="keywords" content="html tutorial template">
     
        <style>
            #btn_cambiar_pass {
                border: solid 1px #00aff0;
                background: #00aff0;
                border-radius: 50px;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 0 30px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #central {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: left;
                text-align: left;
            }

            #btn_validar_email_txt {
                color: white;
                font-size: 1em;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-style: normal;
            }

            #info_text {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }

            #username_text {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-style: normal;
                font-size: 2em;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #header {
                background-color: #7ca157;
                padding: 30px;
                text-align: left;
            }

            #header h1 {
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 24px;
                color: white;
            }

            .horizontal-line {
                border-top: 1px solid black;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="central">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 style="font-size: 2.3rem; color: var(--maincolor); font-weight: bold; width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:10px; font-family: serif;">
Digital Citizen</h1>
       </div>
        <table style="width: 100%; border: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px;"> 
                    <h1 style="font-size: 1.3rem;">{{$user->name }} {{$user->last_name}}</h1>
                    <p style="font-size: 1rem;">TO CHANGE THE EMAIL PRESS THE FOLLOWING LINK</p>
                    <br>
                    <a id="btn_cambiar_pass" href="{{'https://xxxx.ar/cdig/html/build/dashboard/configurations/email/change/validate/?token=' . $mixto  }}">
                        <p id="btn_validar_email_txt">CAMBIAR EMAIL</p>
                    </a> 
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px;">
                        <img height="64px" width="auto" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN......." alt="Gobeners"/>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="horizontal-line"></div>                    
                        <br>
                        <p style="font-size: 1rem; color: black; width: 100%;">For drawbacks<a href="" style="color: blue;">contáctenos</a></p>
                        <p style="font-size: 1rem; color: black; width: 100%;">Information: <a href="" style="color: blue;">Términos y Condiciones</a></p>
                    </td>    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: "the styles are not displaying correctly" - you are going to need to tell us what does or doesn't work. This also isn't really a Laravel or PHP problem, nor an SMTP one, it is just an HTML and CSS problem in the most hostile environment on the planet: email clients.